# Populate Excel sheet with table data

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, excel, exceljs

I've created a Excel task pane app with VS2015 (Excel Web Addin) and Office tools.

On the basis of this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part4), I've also created an ms sql database, including the models and controllers.

**How can I populate the contents of the table Movie in Excel?**

This is the controller:

```
       namespace DatabaseWeb.Controllers
    {
        public class controllerMovie : Controller
        {
            private modelMovie db = new modelMovie();

            // GET: controllerMovie
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(db.Movies.ToList());
            }
```

This is the home.js (not working)

```
    function loadSampleData() {

            var values = getMovies();

            // Run a batch operation against the Excel object model
            Excel.run(function (ctx) {


                // Create a proxy object for the active sheet
                var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
                // Queue a command to write the sample data to the worksheet
                sheet.getRange("B3:D5").values = values;

                // Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
                return ctx.sync();
            })
            .catch(errorHandler);
        }


        function getMovies() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Controllers/controllerMovie",
                success: function (result) {
                    return result;
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    return "fout";
                }
            });

        }
```

Can I request the table Movies data via ajax and what is the exact syntax?

Comment: Is this in excel because if do just use the in built connection functions. 10 easier

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Under data tab there is a section for connections. Https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-import-SQL-Server-data-0f3d2e8f-7d94-4ded-baa6-3b0df183ff98

Comment: i'm creating a Excel task pane app in visual studio with office tools